# Turning a Conceptual diagram to a Relational diagram using (Barker's Notation)

Tags: sql, oracle, datamodel

I have been asked to turn a Conceptual diagram into a Relational diagram using (Barker's Notation).

[This is the Conceptual Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1TTB.png)

[This is the Relational Diagram (Barker's Notation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNGKV.jpg)

I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Are there any errors ?

Comment: Both conceptual and relational diagrams seem to have the problem that any given course can only be a predecessor for one and only one successor course.   This does not seem intuitively correct.   The predecessor/ successor relationship should have a crow's foot in it to indicate that one course can be the predecessor of many other courses.

Comment: Opinions vary about naming conventions and I couldn't find an authoritative source, but in my view logical models like these should purely represent the business entities and their relationships to each other, for discussion with non-technical staff, so the attribute names should be plain English words like 'Name' and 'Start Date', without abbreviations or underscores ('tp1_tea_date_start' etc). Those would be part of the physical model, where they become database column names. Personally I'm not sure ID belongs in a conceptual model unless the tool specifically requires it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.